# Error in compiling tkn154 test applications for TOSSIM

Tags: tinyos

I am trying to compile the example applications under tinyos-2.1.2/apps/tests/tkn154.
The applications compile without any error for both telosb and micaz motes (using make telosb or make micaz).

However, I get a number of issues (attached below) while compiling it for TOSSIM simulation using 'make micaz sim'.
Could anyone please let me know where the error is.

Thanks and regards,

---

TERMINAL OUTPUT:

mkdir -p simbuild/micaz
  placing object files in simbuild/micaz
  writing XML schema to app.xml
  compiling TestAssociateAppC to object file sim.o
ncc -c -shared -fPIC -o simbuild/micaz/sim.o -g -O0 -tossim -fnesc-nido-tosnodes=1000 -fnesc-simulate -fnesc-nido-motenumber=sim_node() -fnesc-gcc=gcc -Wall -Wshadow -Wnesc-all -target=micaz -fnesc-cfile=simbuild/micaz/app.c -board=micasb -DDEFINED_TOS_AM_GROUP=0x22 --param max-inline-insns-single=100000 -I/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/apps/tests/tkn154/nonbeacon-enabled/TestAssociate/device/.. -DIDENT_APPNAME=\"TestAssociateAp\" -DIDENT_USERNAME=\"kbhargava\" -DIDENT_HOSTNAME=\"Precision\" -DIDENT_USERHASH=0x78c52cfbL -DIDENT_TIMESTAMP=0x57e996e9L -DIDENT_UIDHASH=0xe5bdc59eL -I/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154 -I/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/dummies -I/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/interfaces/MCPS -I/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/interfaces/MLME -I/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/interfaces/private -I/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/interfaces/public -I/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/micaz/mac/tkn154 -I/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154 -I/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/timer -I/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154 -Wno-nesc-data-race TestAssociateAppC.nc   -fnesc-dump=components -fnesc-dump=variables -fnesc-dump=constants -fnesc-dump=typedefs -fnesc-dump=interfacedefs -fnesc-dump=tags -fnesc-dumpfile=app.xml
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/Ieee802154NonBeaconEnabledC.nc:62,
                 from TestAssociateAppC.nc:39:
In interface `Timestamp':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/Timestamp.nc:67: warning: declaration of`time' shadows global declaration
/usr/include/time.h:192: warning: location of shadowed declaration
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/TKN154NonBeaconEnabledP.nc:97,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/Ieee802154NonBeaconEnabledC.nc:68,
                 from TestAssociateAppC.nc:39:
In component `DataP':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/DataP.nc: In function`MCPS_DATA.request':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/DataP.nc:103: union has no member named `ieee154'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/DataP.nc:105: union has no member named`ieee154'
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/TKN154NonBeaconEnabledP.nc:98,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/Ieee802154NonBeaconEnabledC.nc:68,
                 from TestAssociateAppC.nc:39:
In component `PibP':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/PibP.nc: In function`Packet.clear':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/PibP.nc:566: union has no member named `ieee154'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/PibP.nc:567: union has no member named`ieee154'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/PibP.nc:568: union has no member named `ieee154'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/PibP.nc: In function`Packet.payloadLength':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/PibP.nc:573: union has no member named `ieee154'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/PibP.nc: In function`Packet.setPayloadLength':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/PibP.nc:578: union has no member named `ieee154'
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/TKN154NonBeaconEnabledP.nc:100,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/Ieee802154NonBeaconEnabledC.nc:68,
                 from TestAssociateAppC.nc:39:
In component`DispatchUnslottedCsmaP':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/DispatchUnslottedCsmaP.nc: In function `updateState':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/DispatchUnslottedCsmaP.nc:255: warning: declaration of`next' shadows global declaration
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/tossim/heap.c:71: warning: location of shadowed declaration
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/DispatchUnslottedCsmaP.nc: In function `tryTransmit':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/DispatchUnslottedCsmaP.nc:328: warning: declaration of`next' shadows global declaration
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/tossim/heap.c:71: warning: location of shadowed declaration
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/DispatchUnslottedCsmaP.nc: In function `tryReceive':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/DispatchUnslottedCsmaP.nc:343: warning: declaration of`next' shadows global declaration
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/tossim/heap.c:71: warning: location of shadowed declaration
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/DispatchUnslottedCsmaP.nc: In function `trySwitchOff':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/mac/tkn154/DispatchUnslottedCsmaP.nc:357: warning: declaration of`next' shadows global declaration
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/tossim/heap.c:71: warning: location of shadowed declaration
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TKN154P.nc:39,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TKN154C.nc:64,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/Ieee802154NonBeaconEnabledC.nc:91,
                 from TestAssociateAppC.nc:39:
In C file:
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420/CC2420.h: At top level:
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420/CC2420.h:132: syntax error before `nx_bool'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420/CC2420.h:132: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420/CC2420.h:133: syntax error before`ack'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420/CC2420.h:134: syntax error before `timesync'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420/CC2420.h:143: syntax error before`}'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420/CC2420.h:143: warning: type defaults to `int' in declaration of`cc2420_metadata_t'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420/CC2420.h:143: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TKN154P.nc:65,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TKN154C.nc:64,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/Ieee802154NonBeaconEnabledC.nc:91,
                 from TestAssociateAppC.nc:39:
In interface `CC2420Tx':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420Tx.nc:52: warning: declaration of`timestamp' shadows global declaration
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420/CC2420.h:135: warning: location of shadowed declaration
In component `CC2420TKN154P':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TKN154P.nc: In function`waitBackoffDoneUnslottedCsma':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TKN154P.nc:524: warning: declaration of `dummy' shadows global declaration
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/tossim/sim_noise.c:283: warning: location of shadowed declaration
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TKN154P.nc: In function`waitBackoffDoneSlottedCsma':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TKN154P.nc:646: warning: declaration of `dummy' shadows global declaration
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/tossim/sim_noise.c:283: warning: location of shadowed declaration
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TKN154P.nc: At top level:
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TKN154P.nc:822: warning: declaration of`time' shadows global declaration
/usr/include/time.h:192: warning: location of shadowed declaration
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TKN154P.nc:901: warning: declaration of `time' shadows global declaration
/usr/include/time.h:192: warning: location of shadowed declaration
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlTransmitC.nc:72,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TKN154C.nc:83,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/Ieee802154NonBeaconEnabledC.nc:91,
                 from TestAssociateAppC.nc:39:
In component`CC2420ControlP':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:58: interface CC2420Ram not found
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:59: interface CC2420Register not found
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:67: interface CC2420Strobe not found
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc: In function `CC2420Power.startOscillator':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:203: interface has no command or event named`write'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:207: interface has no command or event named `strobe'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:209: interface has no command or event named`write'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:215: interface has no command or event named `write'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc: In function`CC2420Power.stopOscillator':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:236: interface has no command or event named `strobe'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc: In function`CC2420Power.rxOn':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:248: interface has no command or event named `strobe'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:249: interface has no command or event named`strobe'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc: In function `CC2420Power.rfOff':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:261: interface has no command or event named`strobe'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc: In function `CC2420Power.flushRxFifo':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:269: warning: declaration of`dummy' shadows global declaration
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/lib/tossim/sim_noise.c:283: warning: location of shadowed declaration
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:278: interface has no command or event named `read'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:283: interface has no command or event named`strobe'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:284: interface has no command or event named `strobe'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc: In function`CC2420Config.sync':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:399: interface has no command or event named `strobe'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc: In function`CC2420Power.rssi':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:425: interface has no command or event named `read'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc: In function`InterruptCCA.fired':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:451: interface has no command or event named `write'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc: In function`writeFsctrl':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:468: interface has no command or event named `write'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc: In function`writeMdmctrl0':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:481: interface has no command or event named `write'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc: In function`writeId':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:511: interface has no command or event named `write'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:515: interface has no command or event named`write'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc: In function `writeTxPower':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlP.nc:519: interface has no command or event named`write'
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/micaz/chips/cc2420/HplCC2420InterruptsC.nc:39,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlTransmitC.nc:88,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TKN154C.nc:83,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/Ieee802154NonBeaconEnabledC.nc:91,
                 from TestAssociateAppC.nc:39:
In interface `GpioCapture':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/interfaces/GpioCapture.nc: At top level:
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/interfaces/GpioCapture.nc:61: warning: declaration of`time' shadows global declaration
/usr/include/time.h:192: warning: location of shadowed declaration
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/micaz/chips/cc2420/HplCC2420InterruptsC.nc:47,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlTransmitC.nc:88,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TKN154C.nc:83,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/Ieee802154NonBeaconEnabledC.nc:91,
                 from TestAssociateAppC.nc:39:
In component `Atm128GpioCaptureC':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/atm128/timer/Atm128GpioCaptureC.nc:71: warning: declaration of`time' shadows global declaration
/usr/include/time.h:192: warning: location of shadowed declaration
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/atm128/timer/HplAtm128Timer1C.nc:53,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/micaz/chips/cc2420/HplCC2420InterruptsC.nc:48,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlTransmitC.nc:88,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TKN154C.nc:83,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/Ieee802154NonBeaconEnabledC.nc:91,
                 from TestAssociateAppC.nc:39:
In component `HplAtm128Timer1P':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/atm128/timer/HplAtm128Timer1P.nc:215: warning: declaration of`time' shadows global declaration
/usr/include/time.h:192: warning: location of shadowed declaration
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/micaz/chips/cc2420/HplCC2420InterruptsC.nc:53,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlTransmitC.nc:88,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TKN154C.nc:83,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/Ieee802154NonBeaconEnabledC.nc:91,
                 from TestAssociateAppC.nc:39:
In component `HplAtm128InterruptPinP':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/atm128/pins/HplAtm128InterruptC.nc:62: component arguments must be constants
In component`HplAtm128InterruptPinP':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/atm128/pins/HplAtm128InterruptC.nc:63: component arguments must be constants
In component `HplAtm128InterruptPinP':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/atm128/pins/HplAtm128InterruptC.nc:64: component arguments must be constants
In component`HplAtm128InterruptPinP':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/atm128/pins/HplAtm128InterruptC.nc:65: component arguments must be constants
In component `HplAtm128InterruptPinP':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/atm128/pins/HplAtm128InterruptC.nc:66: component arguments must be constants
In component`HplAtm128InterruptPinP':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/atm128/pins/HplAtm128InterruptC.nc:67: component arguments must be constants
In component `HplAtm128InterruptPinP':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/atm128/pins/HplAtm128InterruptC.nc:68: component arguments must be constants
In component`HplAtm128InterruptPinP':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/atm128/pins/HplAtm128InterruptC.nc:69: component arguments must be constants
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TKN154C.nc:83,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/Ieee802154NonBeaconEnabledC.nc:91,
                 from TestAssociateAppC.nc:39:
In component `CC2420ControlTransmitC':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlTransmitC.nc:91: component CC2420SpiC not found
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlTransmitC.nc:91: component`CC2420SpiC' is not generic
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlTransmitC.nc:113,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TKN154C.nc:83,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/Ieee802154NonBeaconEnabledC.nc:91,
                 from TestAssociateAppC.nc:39:
In component `CC2420TransmitP':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc:65: interface ChipSpiResource not found
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc:66: interface CC2420Fifo not found
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc:80: interface CC2420Receive not found
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc: In function`CC2420Tx.loadTXFIFO':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc:164: interface has no command or event named `strobe'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc:167: interface has no command or event named`write'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc: At top level:
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc:173: `writeDone' is not in interface`TXFIFO'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc: In function `TXFIFO.writeDone':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc:178: interface has no command or event named`write'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc:182: interface has no command or event named `write'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc: In function`CC2420Tx.send':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc:203: interface has no command or event named `strobe'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc:203: interface has no command or event named`strobe'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc:211: interface has no command or event named `strobe'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc: At top level:
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc:245: warning: declaration of`time' shadows global declaration
/usr/include/time.h:192: warning: location of shadowed declaration
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc: In function `CaptureSFD.captured':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc:297: interface has no command or event named`sfd'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc:320: interface has no command or event named `sfd_dropped'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc: In function`CC2420Tx.modify':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc:336: interface has no command or event named `write'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc: At top level:
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc:351:`releasing' is not in interface `ChipSpiResource'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc: In function`ChipSpiResource.releasing':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc:353: interface has no command or event named `abortRelease'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc: At top level:
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc:363:`receive' is not in interface `CC2420Receive'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc: In function`BackoffAlarm.fired':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc:386: interface has no command or event named `strobe'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc: In function`signalDone':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc:413: interface has no command or event named `attemptRelease'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc: At top level:
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TransmitP.nc:417:`readDone' is not in interface `TXFIFO'
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveC.nc:51,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlTransmitC.nc:141,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420TKN154C.nc:83,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/Ieee802154NonBeaconEnabledC.nc:91,
                 from TestAssociateAppC.nc:39:
In component`CC2420ReceiveP':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveP.nc:214: warning: declaration of `time' shadows global declaration
/usr/include/time.h:192: warning: location of shadowed declaration
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveP.nc:214:`sfd' is not in interface `CC2420Receive'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveP.nc:224:`sfd_dropped' is not in interface `CC2420Receive'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveP.nc:262:`readDone' is not in interface `RXFIFO'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveP.nc: In function`RXFIFO.readDone':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveP.nc:288: interface has no command or event named `continueRead'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveP.nc:321: interface has no command or event named`continueRead'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveP.nc:337: interface has no command or event named `continueRead'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveP.nc:364: interface has no command or event named`receive'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveP.nc: At top level:
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveP.nc:391: `writeDone' is not in interface`RXFIFO'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveP.nc: In function `flush':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveP.nc:457: interface has no command or event named`strobe'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveP.nc:458: interface has no command or event named `strobe'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveP.nc: In function`receive':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveP.nc:474: interface has no command or event named `beginRead'
In component`CC2420ReceiveC':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveC.nc: At top level:
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveC.nc:52: component `CC2420SpiC' is not generic
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveC.nc:69: no match
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveC.nc:70: cannot find`RXFIFO'
...
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ReceiveC.nc:75: cannot find `MDMCTRL1'
In component`CC2420ControlTransmitC':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlTransmitC.nc:92: no match
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlTransmitC.nc:93: cannot find `SRXON'
...
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/chips/cc2420_tkn154/CC2420ControlTransmitC.nc:139: cannot find`SACKPEND'
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/Alarm32khz32C.nc:24:
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/MicaTimer.h:121:2: error: #error "Unknown clock rate. MHZ must be defined to one of 1, 2, 4, or 8."
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/Alarm32khz32C.nc:24,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/timer/Alarm62500hz32C.nc:8,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/Ieee802154NonBeaconEnabledC.nc:92,
                 from TestAssociateAppC.nc:39:
In C file:
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/MicaTimer.h:126: `MHZ' undeclared here (not in a function)
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/MicaTimer.h:126: enumerator value for`PLATFORM_MHZ' not integer constant
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/Alarm32khz32C.nc:32,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/timer/Alarm62500hz32C.nc:8,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/Ieee802154NonBeaconEnabledC.nc:92,
                 from TestAssociateAppC.nc:39:
In component `AlarmOne16C':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/AlarmOne16C.nc:30: syntax error before`TOne'
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/AlarmOne16C.nc:34,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/Alarm32khz32C.nc:32,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/timer/Alarm62500hz32C.nc:8,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/Ieee802154NonBeaconEnabledC.nc:92,
                 from TestAssociateAppC.nc:39:
In component `InitOneP':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/InitOneP.nc:24:`MICA_PRESCALER_ONE' undeclared here (not in a function)
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/Alarm32khz32C.nc:32,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/timer/Alarm62500hz32C.nc:8,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/Ieee802154NonBeaconEnabledC.nc:92,
                 from TestAssociateAppC.nc:39:
In component `AlarmOne16C':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/AlarmOne16C.nc:35:`TOne' undeclared here (not in a function)
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/AlarmOne16C.nc:41: cannot find `Alarm'
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/Counter32khz32C.nc:28,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/Alarm32khz32C.nc:32,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/timer/Alarm62500hz32C.nc:8,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/Ieee802154NonBeaconEnabledC.nc:92,
                 from TestAssociateAppC.nc:39:
In component`CounterOne16C':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/CounterOne16C.nc:24: syntax error before `TOne'
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/CounterOne16C.nc:29:`TOne' undeclared here (not in a function)
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/CounterOne16C.nc:31: cannot find `Counter'
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/Alarm32khz32C.nc:32,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/timer/Alarm62500hz32C.nc:8,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/Ieee802154NonBeaconEnabledC.nc:92,
                 from TestAssociateAppC.nc:39:
In component`Counter32khz32C':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/Counter32khz32C.nc:29: `TOne' undeclared here (not in a function)
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/Counter32khz32C.nc:30:`MICA_DIVIDE_ONE_FOR_32KHZ_LOG2' undeclared here (not in a function)
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/Counter32khz32C.nc:31: `counter_one_overflow_t' undeclared here (not in a function)
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/Counter32khz32C.nc:34: no match
In file included from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/timer/Alarm62500hz32C.nc:8,
                 from /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/Ieee802154NonBeaconEnabledC.nc:92,
                 from TestAssociateAppC.nc:39:
In component`Alarm32khz32C':
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/Alarm32khz32C.nc:33: `TOne' undeclared here (not in a function)
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/Alarm32khz32C.nc:34:`MICA_DIVIDE_ONE_FOR_32KHZ_LOG2' undeclared here (not in a function)
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/mica/Alarm32khz32C.nc:37: no match
/opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tos/platforms/telosb/mac/tkn154/timer/Alarm32khzTo62500hzTransformC.nc:53:2: warning: #warning "Warning: MAC timing is not standard compliant!"
make: *** [sim-exe] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

```
For linux systems try:

Linux Installation

Download JDK and put it in /usr/java directory
sudo chown <output of whoami> -R /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_111/
sudo nano /etc/bash.bashrc
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_111
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

sudo apt-get install update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install git-core
sudo apt-get install tinyos-tools
sudo apt-get install tinyos-source
sudo apt-get install automake
sudo apt-get install avr-libc
sudo apt-get install gcc-msp430
sudo git clone /opt/git://github.com/tinyos/tinyos-main.git
sudo chown <output of whoami> -R tinyos-main/
cd tinyos-main/tools/
./Bootstrap
./configure
make
sudo make install

For MacoS:

Install JDK 
Install homebrew 
Install macports
Install Xcode

sudo port install gcc49           
sudo port select gcc                      
sudo port select gcc mp-gcc49
sudo port install msp430-gcc
sudo port install msp430-libc
sudo port install avr-libc
brew install nesc
cd /opt/
sudo git clone git://github.com/tinyos/tinyos-main.git
cd tinyos-main/tools
sudo ./Bootstrap
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```